# Sitecore Path Analyzer Building Map Error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

When opening the Sitecore path analyzer from the Launchpad i got the following error message at the top (above) the map:

```
"An error occurred when building the map. This map may be incomplete. Please try redeploying the map or rebuilding from historical data."
```

I rebuilt the historical data using the following sitecore admin page:

```
/Sitecore/admin/pathanalyzer.aspx
```

And still got the same error message.

Any idea of how to solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried to find the item corresponding to the map you're trying to visualize and then redeploy it? You can manually set it to the previous step in the workflow and then click on the "Deploy" button in the ribbon. This has helped me in the past.

Comment: I redeployed all maps using map manager in the following page:
/Sitecore/admin/pathanalyzer.aspx

No matter which map I select from the filter I got the same error message although a lot path analyzer paths are constructed? Do you think that if go through the maps and change workflow then redeploy manually will make a different? Is there any side effect for this?.

Comment: I don't think there are side effects for manually redeploying.

Have you looked into Sitecore logs? There might be some errors there, pointing at the source of the error.

Comment: Still can't find anything in log files, but will go through them again.

Comment: did you upgrade your solution?

Comment: No it is not, Is it make any difference? Is there anything I should check if it is?

Comment: yes, I saw this error if you upgrade your solution. Can you try to replicate your issue on a clean solution?

Comment: Something I should add, Both dev and staging environments for the same site is working fine after the rebuild, but this is only on the live environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the log files, when I hit the rebuild from histirical data I got the following error:

```
"Message: Command 'count' failed: not authorized on config to execute command"
```

And after investigating this error the solution was to give a permission for the database user to read from MongoDB config collection using the following:

```
db.grantRolesToUser("user12434", [ { role: "read", db: "config" } ] )
```